# How do you open a folder that is in the same directory as your exe / form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to open a folder that is in the same directory as my form

An example of this would be I have a folder named Folder1 in the directory of my form / exe, and you would click a button to open Folder1, how would I do that?

I tried doing

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", AppDomain.CurrentDomain + @"\Folder1");
```

there was no error, it was just a prompt that said "You need a new app to open this"

Comment: And what was the error when you tried doing the above?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal There was no error, it simply gave me a prompt saying you need a new app to open this

Comment: Did you mean `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe" , AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Folder1");
```

Comment: This is missing the separator (e.g. baskslach). I would highly recomment to use Path.Combine instead of string concatenation.

Comment: And using path combine :       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe",Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Folder1"));